# Select from table with many indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I need to insert ~50 Millions  rows **from** a table with many Non-Clustered indexes.
Does it affect the query run time? Should I disable the indexes before running and rebuild them when it's done?
The table in which I need to insert these rows does not have indexes.

Appreciate your help,

Comment: Indexes in the table you are copying from are not going to slow down inserts into *another* table.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the indexes won't be used (do you have filtering in your "insert into ... select ... " statement?) you'll be fine.
Check the execution plan and verify that you have full table scan on the source table.

Comment: _The table in which I need to insert these rows does not have indexes_ I think Gordons comment said it all

Comment: Yes, I got this, but it is not relevant to the possibility that your  data retrieval from your source table might use indexes which may lead to low performance.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, is there something you would like to say regarding my answer / comment?